# How to save value in MySQL 1,0, when user press b1, b2 and save -1 when no button is pressed by user

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to make a web page in which I give two button b1 and b2 ,b1 color is green and b2 color is red. I want when user click b1 then value save 1 in MySQL data base in column green and when user press b2 then value save 0 in MySQL data base in column red and when user do not press any button then save -1 in database in column nothing.
How can I do this?

My code is:

```
print "<table  width=100% style=table-layout:fixed;>"; 
print "<tr>";
print "<td width=2px style=word-wrap:break-word;;text-align:center;height:40px;>";
print "<form method=post action=check.php>";
print "<input type=hidden value=1 name=red/>";
print "<input type=submit  style=background-color:red/>";
print "</form>";
print "</td>"; 
print "<td width=2px style=word-wrap:break-word;;text-align:center;height:40px;>";
print "<form method=post action=check.php>";
print "<input type=hidden value=0 name=green/>";
print "<input type=submit  style=background-color:green/>";
print "</form>";
print "</td>";
print "</tr>";
print "</table>";
```

Comment: how do you know when user "not pressing" or "not yet pressing"?

Comment: sir as check box has a click event if check save 1 if unchecked save 0 ,i am trying to capture button click event.but i am not getting means if both button is not clicked then through javascript  i want insert -1 in database

Comment: Try to use AJAX Requests onclick/onchange event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your question is:

`"I have 3 columns in Database, Column GREEN, RED and NOTHING. When user clicks on Button 1 => Update Column GREEN 1 / IF user clicks on Button 2 => Update Column RED 0" If Nothing is pressed update column NOTHING 0`

Answer:

```
1. by default in column NOTHING have value 0
2. give button 1 id = btn1, button 2 id = btn2
3. when any button is clicked check for which button user clicked on,
    You can use jQuery [.click()][1] event to do it.
4. when user click on any button, check the button clicked and send [ajax request][2] to php page, 
    where you have mysql state to update your database columns.
5. Ask per button clicked [update your database column][3] and update NOTHING column to 0

http://api.jquery.com/click/
https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html
```